# What are some implementations of JSR 352 (Java for batch)?

Tags: spring-batch, jsr, jsr352

Can we say ***Spring Batch*** is an implementation of the JSR 352 (spec for Batch Applications for the Java Platform) ?

> What are some other implementations of JSR 352 ?

Comment: For this kind of question a good search on the net can give you all the information you are asking for (try googling for 'JSR 352' keywords, second link, first sentence - just for example)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSR 352 Spring Batch vs. Java EE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25630921/jsr-352-spring-batch-vs-java-ee)

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci Your comment leads me to `Key point here: the JSR-352 specification provides a way to control the flow based on the exit status of jobs.` Take into account Google is personalizing result sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Spring Batch does implement the SE requirements for JSR-352.  You can read more about that in the documentation here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/jsr-352.html

**EDIT:** This implementation was removed in Spring Batch 5. Versions of Spring Batch prior to Spring Batch 5 do include an implementation of JSR-352.

Comment: it isn't the case anymore
https://spring.io/blog/2022/11/24/spring-batch-5-0-goes-ga#jsr-352-implementation-removal

Answer (score 2):

**Jberet** is an another implementation of the JSR-352. It is stable and used for JEE projects, Wildfly has an integrated support for jberet with Jboss EAP.
https://github.com/jberet/jsr352